# Where is Jimmy's father?

Tags: lateral-thinking, calculation-puzzle, humor

(It's an old soviet math problem, no tricks or anything here)

---

Jimmy is 21 years younger than his mother.

Six years from now, Jimmy's mother will be five times as old as Jimmy.

Where is Jimmy's father?

Comment: You should word it as "five times as old" to remove ambiguity.

Comment: @ Thomas Blue This question was asked as " Where is Jenifer's Husband" on this site a few years ago. So it is a duplicate. Please check

Comment: @ DEEM That is true. In russian it was called "Where is the father" so my searches for duplicate proved worthless

Comment: No issue. Happens all the time. Funny puzzle though

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, first I have to solve the math problem, I guess.

> Let $x$ equal Jimmy's age. 
>  
>  This means $x+21$ is the mother's starting age. In 6 years, Jimmy will be $x+6$ and his mother will be $x+27$. 
>  
>  So, $(x+6)*5 = x+27$ 
>  
>  $5x+30 = x+27$ 
>  
>  $5x + 3 = x$ 
>  
>  $4x = -3$ 
>  
>  $x = -3/4$ 
>  
>  Yeah, I see where this is going. Jimmy is exactly -9 months old, which means his father is right where his mother is, most likely.

Comment: Nice! You get the tick!

Answer (score 24):

Easy math:

> Let $x$ represent Jimmy's age.
>  Let $y$ represent Jimmy's mother's age. 
>  We can convert this into two equations:
> $x+21=y$
> $5*(x+6) = y+6$
>  Substituting the first equation into the second equation via isolated y:
> $5x+30=x+21+6$
>  Subtract x and 30 from both sides of the equation:
> $4x = -3$
>  Jimmy is -3/4 years old. This is the length of a pregnancy (9 months).
>  Jimmy's father is currently sleeping with his mother as he is being conceived.

Comment: Looks like someone else beat me by a matter of seconds... so close

Comment: Still nice! You get the sympathy and an upvote!

Comment: 1 min 29 sec to be exact... @kanoo Nice job tho, +1!